# Not able to launch application in emulator using Appium selenium java

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, appium

Code

```java
public void FirstTestCase() throws Exception {
    softAssert = new SoftAssert();

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

      capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nilesh2");
      capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
      capabilities.setCapability("app",
      "C:\\NileshData\\Automation\\MobileAutomationCSG\\src\\test\\java\\utils\\ApiDemos-debug.apk"
      );
    capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("appWaitForLaunch", false);

     AppiumDriver driver;
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

}
```

---

```
ERROR : org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 404. Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource 
Host info: host: 'INGAWALENILESH', 
Build info: version: '4.9.0', revision: 'd7057100a6'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.17'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:app=C:\NileshData\Automation\MobileAutomationCSG\src\test\java\utils\ApiDemos-debug.apk, appium:appWaitForLaunch=false, appium:deviceName=Nilesh2, appium:noReset=true, platformName=ANDROID}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {app: C:\NileshData\Automation\Mo..., appWaitForLaunch: false, deviceName: Nilesh2, noReset: true, platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {app: C:\NileshData\Automation\Mo..., appWaitForLaunch: false, deviceName: Nilesh2, noReset: true, platformName: ANDROID}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
```

or even some times getting below

```
 Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\ingawalenilesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk'. Original error: The 'java.exe' binary could not be found neither in PATH nor under JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.17_8\bin\bin)
```

Can we resolve above